# Rails - A gem to add stuff to my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

When I build an API to handle my classes, if I want to add data, I have to make CURL commands through the terminal. Is there a simple way to do this ? So I'm looking for a gem (or other stuff) to handle my database easily, by myself (with no access for the users)

I've already found this : https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db
But it's only to view content, not to add some.

Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, like Ruff9 said, what's up with you not using rails console?

Comment: It's a bit tedious, if my class can have web links and pictures, pretty harsh to add this manually.

Comment: Well yeah, if you want to upload files, then build some kind of admin interface.

Comment: Yeah, I think i'm gonna do this. But I just wanted to avoid useless views in my rails app.

Comment: They are not useless. You're going to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the [Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) (again?) closely as this is one of the central functions of the rails framework.  If you are building an application with rails, you should be able to use the `rails generate` command to set up scaffolds, models, controllers, etc.  And when you set up models, they will be persisted to whichever database you have set up (sqlite by default) when you call `save` on them.